# Pandas Merge - put all join-column data under one output column instead of two?

Tags: python, join, merge, rename

I have two CSV files, with the following schemas:

CSV1 columns:

```
"Id","First","Last","Email","Company"
```

CSV2 columns:

```
"PersonId","FirstName","LastName","Em","FavoriteFood"
```

If I load them each into a Pandas DataFrame and do `newdf = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['Last', 'First'], right_on=['LastName','FirstName'])`

Then a CSV export of the joined DataFrame has a schema of:

```
"Id","First","Last","Email","Company","PersonId","FirstName","LastName","Em","FavoriteFood"
```

- All the rows that were only in CSV1 have a first name printed under
  "First."
- All the rows that were only in CSV2 have a first name printed under
  "FirstName."
- All the rows that were in both CSV file have a first
  name *(the exact same value - which is to be expected, since it was a
  "join on" value)* printed under both columns.
- Same problem for "Last" & "LastName."

What I'd like is an output schema more like this:

```
"Id","First","Last","Email","Company","PersonId","Em","FavoriteFood"
```

- It should have all of the "first names" under the column "First" (and equivalent for "Last").

Most relational database software I'm familiar with does this *(the left-side join-column names win the naming war)*.  Does Pandas have a syntax for instructing it to do so?

I can do `df1.merge(df2.rename(columns = {'LastName':'Last', 'FirstName':'First'}), how='outer', on=['Last', 'First'])`, but stylistically, it drives me crazy to hard-code the same column-names twice in my source code.  It's more to fix if I change the column names in the CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to just merge the same way but drop columns that you'd like to remove.

```
newdf.drop(['LastName','FirstName'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: That still involves typing the same column name twice in my source code, though, which is what I'm trying to avoid.  It just does it on a different line.  (Also, I don't have my IDE up & running, but it looks to me like it would end up leaving me with holes in my data under "First" for the "only existed in df2" rows.)